# "Hello World" in Languages starting with Q, U and Y

Tags: programming-languages, esoteric-languages

I started a little fun project - collecting a "hello World"-program for every letter in the alphabet. For example *Ada* for *A*, *Boo* for *B*, *C++* for *C*, *D* for *D*, *Erlang* for *E*, and so on

But i got a little stuck i can't find any programming languages starting with the letter **Q**, **U** and **Y**

Any languages anyone, preferable not from the esolang wiki?

**Update:**

just in case anyone is interested i have completed my collection and made it available 
[in my blog](http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2010/09/07/hello-world-abc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this [The Hello World Collection](http://helloworldcollection.de/). For "Y" use the [`Yacas`](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/homepage.html) programmable computer algebra system with : `WriteString("Hello World")`

Comment: You should tell "The Hello World Collection" about that one!

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubercode for a U language, it's got a Hello World program in the article!

Answer (score 1):

For "Q" use [QBasic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic)

Answer (score 1):

[Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) has the perfect response to this.

There is an [ongoing `Hello, World!` challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world), and it currently has at least two languages for every letter of the alphabet.

To view the languages and solutions in one place, click "Show code snippet" in the question, scroll down, and click "Run code snippet".

Some relevant languages: [Q](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(programming_language_from_Kx_Systems)), [Quipu](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Quipu), [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), [Unlambda](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unlambda), [Y](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Y), and [Yorick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorick_(programming_language)).

The 'U' ones I selected are from the esolang wiki, but they are the most popular two. There were several other 'U' languages in the list besides them.